# How to add extra empty row to fill region-body in <fo:table/>

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

When using apache FOP to generate the document, I want to add the **extra empty row** to fill the `body-region`. As the second picture below, the content of `table 2` is always on the same page (using `keep-together.within-page="always"` property), the space on the **page 1** is not enough for `table 2`, so this table is rendered on **page 2**. Therefore, in **pgae 1**, I want to insert an empty row to the end of the `body-region`, and on **page 2 - last page**, `table 1` is added the constant number of empty rows (in this case is 13) before the `table 2`. How to I do that?

[image]
Pic1: table 1 and empty row added

[image]Pic2: table 1 empty row and table 2

Comment: What is special about there being 13 empty rows on page 2? Why exactly 13?

Comment: Hi Tony, it can be 5, 10, or 15; but not equal 0, because my client requirement the `table 2` can't stand alone on page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, in general, tell a table to make enough rows to fill a space.  The formatter formats what's in its input, and it won't add table rows that aren't in the input. If you were using the XSLT Extensions from the Print and Page Layout Community Group, then you could work out the size of the real rows and then also generate the empty rows needed to give the effect that you want, but that's about the only way.

The usual way to fake something like what you want is to use a background image from one of the page regions for the table cell borders.  If you can get by without the horizontal borders on empty rows, then the image could be just the column borders, and the table cells (or `fo:table-row`) for the real rows could generate their own horizontal borders.

If you need the horizontal borders on the empty rows in the background image, then the real rows would have to have a white background to stop the horizontal borders from the background image being visible.  You probably need to take care that the real rows are always an integer multiple of the height of the empty rows in the background image so that you don't appear to have an extra tall or short row immediately after the real rows.

You can put 'table 2' at the bottom of the page either by floating it to the bottom (which FOP can't do IIRC) or by including 'table 2' in the `fo:static-content` for the `fo:region-after` of the last page.  That requires both that the page with 'table 2' is the last page of its page sequence and that you set up an `fo:page-sequence-master` that selects the correct `fo:simple-page-master` for `page-position="last"` so that the `fo:static-content` that contains 'table 2' is used on the last page.

Comment: Sincerely thanks Tony, I'll try to use the XSLT Extensions, but it seems to difficult a bit, could you give me some suggestions for this issue?

Comment: The instructions are at https://www.w3.org/community/ppl/wiki/XSLTExtensions.  It requires that you can add an extension to your XSLT processor.

Comment: I suggest that you: generate 'table 1' on a very tall page; run 'table 1' through the XSLT Extensions so that you can find out its height; if 'table 2' isn't always the same height, also get the area tree for 'table 2' to find its height; generate 'table 1' and 'table 2' for real, with extra rows in 'table 1' if necessary. One way to generate 'table 1' with extra rows is for the template for 'table 1' (or its `fo:table-body`) to have a parameter for how many extra rows to add. If you are using XSLT 2.0 or XSLT 3.0, all this will be easier than if you are using XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Hi Tony, it sounds not simple. According to your suggestion "_The usual way to fake something like what you want is to use a background image......_", I want to edit a little bit,  Is there a way **to create two overlapping tables at the same position** (I called `table 1` and `table 1.1` - below the `table 1`) in `xsl-region-body`. `table 1` contains the real data, and the  `table 1.1` only contain the empty rows with the row's height is fixed. The rows in `table 1.1` always fill to end of `region-body` and will be covered by rows data in `table 1`. It can be done?

Comment: With AH Formatter, you could do 'table 1.1' as in an absolutely positioned `fo:block-container` with a lower `z-index`, put 'table 1.1' in a separate `fo:region-body`, or float 'table 1.1' to the bottom of the region. With FOP, you could put 'table 1.1' in the `fo:static-content` for, say, `xsl:region-after` (with a suitably large `extent` value). The relative z-index of the regions is not well defined in XSL 1.1 (https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-ext.html#ext-others), but that might put the 'table 1.1' in the outer region below 'table 1'.

Comment: Many thanks to you, Tony, I appreciate your support!

Comment: Hi Tony, I have one more question, which method in the XSLT Extensions to find out the `table 1` height as your suggest: " _generate 'table 1' on a very tall page; run 'table 1' through the XSLT Extensions so that you can find out its heigh_" ?

Comment: See https://www.w3.org/community/ppl/wiki/XSLTExtensions#Example_XSLT. Make a variable containing a dummy document that has a very long page-height. Include a copy of 'table 1' in the dummy document. Make sure that it has an ID. Use `ppl:area-tree()` to get the area tree for the dummy document. Use `ppl:block-by-id()` to get the block for 'table 1'. Use `ppl:block-bpd()` to get the height of the table.

Comment: Thank you for all your assistance, Tony. I really appreciate your help in resolving the problem!